# Sum of numeric and empty text values

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I have a series of cells that either return a numeric value or IFERROR "".

I am then looking to do a grand total of the cells i.e. `A1+B1+C1`, but where `C1` has a value of `""`, how can I get a grand total of `A1+B1` without returning `#VALUE!` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use SUM, which excludes text values:

```
=SUM(A1:C1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in `sum` formula of excel. As it excludes the text fields and sums up only numeric values.

```
=SUM(A1:C1)
```